# Netlify submit button doesnt work how can i fix it?

Tags: html, css, forms, netlify

When I click to submit button nothing happens. Can someone help me?

```html
<form name="Personal_Contact" method="POST" netlify>
  <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Name... *" required>
  <input type="email" class="inputs" placeholder="Email...">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="textarea" placeholder="Your message... *" required minlength="10"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="rightbutton"> SEND </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Should that not be [`data-netlify="true"`](https://docs.netlify.com/forms/setup/)

Comment: i looked at the tutorial, it says both data-netlify="true" and netlify is ok.

Comment: Please use the imgur embedded images that SO can handle and update the question - however in this case the image does not make us any wiser

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1jaU8NX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add an action to fix the problem.

```
<form name="Personal_Contact" method="POST" netlify action="/">
  <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Name... *" required>
  <input type="email" class="inputs" placeholder="Email...">
  <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="textarea" placeholder="Your message... *" required minlength="10"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="rightbutton"> SEND </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. I deployed the site again and add name="" to my inputs and it works now.